# WebdriverIO + Jasmine: How to exclude a specific test file when running a suite based on that test file name

Tags: jasmine, webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio, wdio-jasmine

We are on latest 8.X WebdriverIO version and latest Jasmine 4.X at this moment, using latest Node 18.X.

In my Wdio.conf.js file I have suite:

`all: [ 'path/test1.js', 'path/test2.js'],`

test1.js has a Describe with value "SMOKE test 1", while test2.js has "test 2".

I want to run --suite=all but exclude all files that DOESN'T contain "SMOKE" in the title, or run --suite=all but include only tests which contains "SMOKE" in the title.
Is this possible, and how? I'm having real troubles finding examples for this case. Can we use grep for this example somehow? I don't have an idea how can we do it.

Basically, the idea is to run only smoke test from some suite. We are not using Mocha and Cucumber runners which have additional tagging, so we are basically running suites all the time. I don't want to create more suites and divide tests in separate suites, we have to many test files.

I tried following the documentation, but I'm having troubles using their example:
grep -r -l --include "*.js" "myText" | wdio wdio.conf.js

Answer (score 1):

with WebdriverIO 7.21 & Jasmine 3.7 the following works stable, hope it's not changed in Wdio 8 or Jasmine 4.
At least the `jasmineOpts` (instead of older `jasmineNodeOpts`) works fine in wdio 7, but is correctly mentioned from  [wdio 8 docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks/#jasmine-options).

A working package.json script is using the **Jasmine's grep**:

```
"smoketest": "wdio run wdio.local.conf.js --suite=temp --jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke"
```

where:

`--suite=temp` is defined in the wdio.local.conf.js suites and runs only those spec files,

`--jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke` finds '_smoke' part in the test (`it`) titles AND `describe` titles inside the above spec files and runs only them.

This would run the full describe

```
describe(`Suite 1 _smoke any other text`, () => {
   it('Test 1-1', async () => {});
   it('Test 1-2', async () => {});
});
```

and tests from another describe(s) like:

```
it('Test 2-1 _smoke is for smoke runs', async () => {});
```

Non-matching tests (its) are skipped.

`_smoke` can be any other text tag you add to the titles.

---

**Additional info:**

1. Of course, you remember to add an extra `--` to run an npm script with extra options :)
   (I used to forget)))

package.json script:

```
"localtest": "wdio run wdio.local.conf.js --suite=temp"
```

command line:

```
$ npm run localtest -- --jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke
> wdio run wdio.local.conf.js --suite=temp --jasmineOpts.grep=_smoke
```

2. 

`--spec=_smoke` would find and launch the *filenames* that contain '_smoke' (e.g. `test1_smoke.js`), *not* the Describe names, but may be useful. [Wdio docs here](https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites/#run-selected-tests).

Please note that "When the `--spec` option is provided, it will [override](https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites/#run-selected-tests) any patterns defined by the config or capability level's specs parameter", so `--suite=temp --spec=_smoke` will run **all** files from the config suite named `temp` **AND all** files with matching filename.

---

3. 

I could not make `--grep=_smoke` work, it starts all suites and tests. Seems to have no effect for Wdio runner + Jasmine.

Also failed with **multiple tags** like
`--jasmineOpts.grep='@describe_tag||@test_tag'`,
`--jasmineOpts.grep='@describe_tag|@test_tag'`,
`--jasmineOpts.grep='@describe_tag&&@test_tag'`.
Maybe someone will have more luck.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I managed to run my whole suite and use --jasmineOpts.grep to exclude everything that doesn't have desired tag, and it works perfectly!
Thank you so much for reply, I can now re-arrange the structure of the tests not to have so many foldesr, but instead we can just use the custom naming in describe blocks and run based on them. So good!

Comment: Let me also share the versions of packages.
Using:
 - wdio 8.4 (@wdio set of packages on this version)
 - jasmine 4.3.1

    "@wdio/cli": "^8.4.0",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^8.4.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.4.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.4.0"